# PKIX error while receiving server certificate by InstallCert.java

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate

I am Trying to get servers ssl certificate by using installCert.java

in the link Below

https://github.com/escline/InstallCert/blob/master/InstallCert.java

I can get server cert for some servers but while trying to get some servers certificates I get error below

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
```

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:

I searched, but everyone says that you should enter your cert file to java cacerts but I use this java class to fetch certificate file.

Also I get the error at  `socket.startHandshake();`

```
    System.out.println("Opening connection to " + host + ":" + port + "...");
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);
    socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting SSL handshake...");
        socket.startHandshake();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("No errors, certificate is already trusted");
    } catch (SSLException e) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that your JVM does not trust the server certificate

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

You need to include **manually** the CA root certificate in the truststore of the JVM, by default the cacerts file. The CA root is the issuer of the server certificate or of an intermediate entity if exists

Comment: are there any way to make him trust :) I want to export and import certificates by code

Comment: No, you can't. The root CA certificate is not sent by SSL server (in fact it is optional, but in reality it is not sent by most servers). It is assumed that the operation of adding the root CA to the truststore must be done separately. This is a security measure which avoid trusting a CA automatically. Note that if you did, an attacker could send the trust certificate on the first connection

Comment: Of course you could avoid this exception by installing a TrustManager that will trust all the certificates, but do not use this on a real system